# nativescript-urlhandler plugin: what is the desired scheme?

Tags: plugins, nativescript

I'm writing an app with NativeScript v 6 and Angular v 8.

I want to use this plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-urlhandler

I'm using it for some SSO authentication.

It says in the documentation in the AndroidManifest file that we must set our desired scheme:

What is this scheme and how do I know what is my desired scheme?

Answer (score 0):

The **desired scheme** is something of your own choice. In the example they use **myapp**, you may replace it with your app name. This is the name your Authenticator will use to open your app when the authentication is done. You may compare this to a redirect url you will use on web apps.